# Laravel group by change keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have reservations and their start times. Now I need to raport it.

```
        $monthlyAmounts = Reservation::all()
        ->groupBy(function ($proj) {
            return cdate($proj->start_time)->format('Y-m');
        })
        ->map(function ($month) {
            return $this->sumTime($month);
        });
```

sumTime is my function to calculate diff between start time and end time.
cdate is helper -> carbon::parse($date)..

Result of this is:

```
array:2 [▼
  "2020-01" => 60
  "2020-02" => 420
]
```

#### Need

But for API it would be better to get like this:

```
[
    "2020" => [
        '01' => 60,
        '02' => 30
    ],
    "2021" => [
        '01' => 30,
    ]
]
```

#### My try

Unfortunately I can't make it like that. I tried:

```
    $monthlyAmounts = Reservation::all()
        ->groupBy(function ($proj) {
            return cdate($proj->start_time)->format('Y-m');
        })
        ->map(function ($month) {
            return $this->sumTime($month);
        })
        ->mapToGroups(function ($item,$key) {
            $arrkey = explode('-',$key);
            return [$arrkey[0]=>[$arrkey[1]=>$item]];
        });
```

But It makes this:

```
array:1 [▼
  2020 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "01" => 60
    ]
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "02" => 420
    ]
  ]
]
```

So I can't do $res['2020']['01']. How to do It?

Comment: use `return [$arrkey[1]=>$item];`

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie nope then i have  
```array:2 [▼
  "01" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 60
  ]
  "02" => array:1 [▼
    0 => 420
  ]
]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$monthlyAmounts = Reservation::all()
        ->groupBy(function ($proj) {
            return cdate($proj->start_time)->format('Y');
        })
        ->map(function ($items) {
            return $items->groupBy(function($item) {
                return cdate($item->start_time)->format('m');
            })
            ->map(function($month) {
                return $this->sumTime($month);
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: $items->groupBy(function($item) {
                return cdate($proj->start_time)->format('m');
            }) changed $proj to $item, and 
            Collection {#532 ▼
                #items: array:1 [▼
                2020 => null
          ]
        }
You missed return in map! Now it works :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another method using foreach loop

```
...
$monthlyAmounts = Reservation::all();
$new = [];
foreach($monthlyAmounts as $key => $val)
{
  $dis = explode('-', $key);
  $new[$dis[0]][$dis[1] = $val;
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: Yes but I wanted more 'laravel-like' solution :)